# How can one reduce the spacing between inline form inputs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 to format a simple inline form.  Obviously I want to reduce the spacing between these buttons, but can't for the life of me figure out how.  I tried deleting all non-bootstrap CSS, but the problem remained.

How can I reduce the spacing between these buttons?

**My html:**

```
<div class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div id="instructions" ng-repeat="instruction in racing.Instructions" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" name="Description" ng-model="instruction.Description" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="order">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <button ng-click="removeInstruction(instruction)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**The output:**
[image]

**Fiddle:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/ppwsgchh/

Comment: Can you setup a demo of the above output?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the padding on the buttons. You can fix it by setting your own. Here is a working example:

```css
#instructions button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm {
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div id="instructions" ng-repeat="instruction in racing.Instructions" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" name="Description" ng-model="instruction.Description" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="order">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <button ng-click="removeInstruction(instruction)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="instructions" ng-repeat="instruction in racing.Instructions" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" name="Description" ng-model="instruction.Description" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="order">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <button ng-click="removeInstruction(instruction)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="instructions" ng-repeat="instruction in racing.Instructions" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" name="Description" ng-model="instruction.Description" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="order">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <button ng-click="removeInstruction(instruction)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I find that this does nothing but increase the padding within the button itself.  The space between the buttons is still present.  In your code snippet it is just collapsing the elements.  Expand the width of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L0ayqsqd/

Answer (score 1):

Any reason the `minus-sign` button can't be in the same button group as the `chevron`'s?

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="order">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </button>

       <!-- Minus button added to the button group -->
       <button ng-click="removeInstruction(instruction)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap [Input Groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) might help depending on your ultimate needs.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div id="instructions" ng-repeat="instruction in racing.Instructions" class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="Description2" ng-model="instruction.Description" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-btn" role="group" aria-label="order">
                        
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          </button>
          <button ng-click="removeInstruction(instruction)" class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="Description" ng-model="instruction.Description" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-btn" role="group" aria-label="order">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          </button>
          <button ng-click="removeInstruction(instruction)" class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="Description" ng-model="instruction.Description" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-btn" role="group" aria-label="order">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          </button>
          <button ng-click="removeInstruction(instruction)" class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```